# Изменение кнопки "В корзину" на "Выберите" если у товара есть апселлы

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким или сможет помочь. Нужно в каталоге у карточек менять текст на кнопке "В корзину" на "Выберите" если у этого товара есть апселлы. При нажатии на кнопку "Выберите" человека должно перекидывать на персональную карточку этого товара.

Пробовала делать вот так, но всё крашится

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'saphira_theme_product_btn_text');
function saphira_theme_product_btn_text( $product ) {
    $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();
    if(!empty($upsells) && isset($upsells))
    {
        $text = 'Выбрать';
    }
    return __($text, 'woocommerce');
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'saphira_theme_product_cart_url');
function saphira_theme_product_cart_url( $product ) {
    $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();
    if(!empty($upsells) && isset($upsells))
    {
        $url = wc_get_cart_url();
    }
    return __($url, 'woocommerce');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все фильтры изменяют стандартное поведение кнопок на страницах каталога и таксономий.

отключим ajax добавление в корзину для товаров у которых есть апсейлы

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_supports', 'disable_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );

function disable_ajax_add_to_cart( $ajax_add_to_cart, $feature, $product ){
    return $feature === 'ajax_add_to_cart' && ( is_shop() || is_product_taxonomy() ) && $product->get_upsell_ids() ? false : $ajax_add_to_cart;
}
```

изменим тест кнопки для товаров у которых есть апсейлы

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function change_add_to_cart_text( $button_name, $product ) {
    return ( is_shop() || is_product_taxonomy() ) && $product->get_upsell_ids() ? __( 'Choose', 'theme_domain' ) : $button_name;
}
```

изменим ссылку для товаров у которых есть апсейлы

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'change_add_to_cart_url', 10, 2 );

function change_add_to_cart_url( $url, $product ) {
    return ( is_shop() || is_product_taxonomy() ) && $product->get_upsell_ids() ? $product->get_permalink() : $url;
}
```